# ArrayIterator's valid() always show true

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have a problem with `ArrayIterator::valid()` method. It always return true. I don't know if I don't understand how should it work, or am I doing something wrong...

I use Doctrine's Paginator
http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.1/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.Tools.Pagination.Paginator.html

It does implement `\Countable` and `\IteratorAggregate`. The method `getIterator()` returns `\ArrayIterator`.

In view I do:

```
<?php foreach ($this->paginator as $message): ?>
    <?php var_dump($this->paginator->valid()); ?> // Fatal error. Method does not exist
    <?php var_dump($this->paginator->getIterator()->valid()); ?> // <-- it always return true
    <p>Teeeeeest</p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I also tried:

```
<?php $paginator = $this->paginator->getIterator(); ?>
<?php foreach ($paginator as $message): ?>
    <?php var_dump($paginator->valid()); ?> // <-- it always return true
    <p>Teeeeeest</p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

`var_dump($this->paginator)` shows that I have 2 records. So I should get `true` in first iteration and `false` in second iteration. Am I correct? So why does it return always `true`

Comment: The `foreach` takes only valid entries, so `$paginator->valid()` is always valid at this point.  if you use `$paginator->next()` that will end in `false` after the last entry was proccessed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The foreach takes only valid entries, so `$paginator->valid()` is always valid at this point. If you use `$paginator->next()` that will end in `false` after the last entry was proccessed.

So `$paginator->valid()` is used with `$paginator->next()` not within a `foreach`

Try to test it like that.

```
$paginator->reset();
while($paginator->valid()){
    $entrie = $paginator->current();

    $paginator->next();
}
```

or test it with `var_dump($paginator->valid());` **after** the foreach. (But maybe the foreach will reset the iterator after iteration)

:-)

Comment: Hmm.. thanks foe explanation. I'll test it and accept your answer. I have one more question. How can I check if it's last element in array inside foreach loop?

Comment: Do it with `$c=$paginator->count()-1;$idx=0;` Then within foreach `if($idx==$c) {echo 'last entrie';}  $idx++;` or some like that